# How would I make this timer into a function which updates every second?

Tags: python

```py
def timer()
    import time
    x, y, z = 0, 0, 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(str(z) + ":" + str(y) + ":" + str(x))
        x += 1
        if x == 3:
            x = 0
            y += 1
            if y == 3:
                x, y = 0, 0
                z += 1
                if z == 3:
                    x, y, z = 0, 0, 0
```

I tried returning the value but it would only as it would only return 0:0:0 once, and I cant figure out how to keep it constantly updating as a function.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine if you correct the syntax errors:

```
import time


def timer():
    x, y, z = 0, 0, 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(str(z) + ":" + str(y) + ":" + str(x))
        x += 1
        if x == 3:
            x = 0
            y += 1
            if y == 3:
                x, y = 0, 0
                z += 1
                if z == 3:
                    x, y, z = 0, 0, 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    timer()
```

```
0:0:0
0:0:1
0:0:2
0:1:0
0:1:1
0:1:2
0:2:0
0:2:1
```

If you were ever to decide to scale this timer up (e.g. having more spaces in the clock), storing the values in a list rather than in three hardcoded variables would give you more flexibility:

```
import time


def timer() -> None:
    clock = [0] * 3
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(":".join(str(d) for d in clock[::-1]))
        i = 0
        while True:
            clock[i] += 1
            if clock[i] < 3:
                break
            clock[i] = 0
            i = (i + 1) % len(clock)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    timer()
```

This gives the same output as-is, but you can make the "clock" arbitrarily larger by changing this line:

```
    clock = [0] * 3
```

and you can make each digit count arbitrarily higher by changing this line:

```
            if clock[i] < 3:
```